# How to pass a CustomDataAsset to a DataContext to run custom expectations on a batch?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, great-expectations

I have a `CustomPandasDataset` with a custom expectation

```
from great_expectations.data_asset import DataAsset
from great_expectations.dataset import PandasDataset
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

class CustomPandasDataset(PandasDataset):

    _data_asset_type = "CustomPandasDataset"
      
    @DataAsset.expectation(["column", "datetime_match", "datetime_diff"])
    def expect_column_max_value_to_match_datetime(self, column:str, datetime_match: datetime = None, datetime_diff: tuple = None) -> dict:
        """
        Check if data is constantly updated by matching the max datetime column to a
        datetime value or to a datetime difference.
        """
        max_datetime = self[column].max()

        if datetime_match is None:

            from datetime import date

            datetime_match = date.today()

        if datetime_diff:
            
            from datetime import timedelta

            success = (datetime_match - timedelta(*datetime_diff)) <= max_datetime <= datetime_match

        else:

            success = (max_datetime == datetime_match)

        result = {
            "data_max_value": max_datetime,
            "expected_max_value": str(datetime_match),
            "expected_datetime_diff": datetime_diff
        }

        return {
            "success": success,
            "result": result
        }
```

I want to run the expectation `expect_column_max_value_to_match_datetime` to a given pandas dataframe

```
expectation_suite_name = "df-raw-expectations"

suite = context.create_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name, overwrite_existing=True)

df_ge = ge.from_pandas(df, dataset_class=CustomPandasDataset)

batch_kwargs = {'dataset': df_ge, 'datasource': 'df_raw_datasource'}

# Get batch of data
batch = context.get_batch(batch_kwargs, suite)
```

which I get from a DataContext, now when I run expectations on this batch

```
datetime_diff = 4,
batch.expect_column_max_value_to_match_datetime(column='DATE', datetime_diff=datetime_diff)
```

I got the following error

```
AttributeError: 'PandasDataset' object has no attribute 'expect_column_max_value_to_match_datetime'
```

According to the docs I've specified the `dataset_class=CustomPandasDataset` attribute when constructing the GreatExpectations dataset, indeed **running the expectations on** `df_ge` **works but not on the batch of data**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/guides/how_to_guides/creating_and_editing_expectations/how_to_create_custom_expectations.html)

> To use custom expectations in a datasource or DataContext, you need to define the custom DataAsset in the datasource configuration or batch_kwargs for a specific batch.

so pass `CustomPandasDataset` through the `data_asset_type` parameter of `get_batch()` function

```
# Get batch of data
batch = context.get_batch(batch_kwargs, suite, data_asset_type=CustomPandasDataset)
```

or define it in the context Configuration

```
from great_expectations.data_context.types.base import DataContextConfig
from great_expectations.data_context import BaseDataContext

data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
    ...
    datasources={
        "sales_raw_datasource": {
            "data_asset_type": {
                "class_name": "CustomPandasDataset",
                "module_name": "custom_dataset",
            },
            "class_name": "PandasDatasource",
            "module_name": "great_expectations.datasource",
        }
    },
    ... 
    )
context = BaseDataContext(project_config=data_context_config)
```

where `CustomPandasDataset` is available from the module/script `custom_dataset.py`